# Saving User ID in Shared Preferences Android

Tags: java, android, unique-id

I just asked a question about this but I want to go at it a different way. When a user edits his/her profile and hits the save button, I want to be able to generate a random number using UUID. I want this ID to stay the same if the user goes back and edits their profile a second time (if they press 'save' again I want to retain the ID that was generated the first time they pressed 'save'). I have the following code working to save other data, but I'm not sure how to include a check that can find out if an ID has already been generated. Here is my code:

```
public void save(View view) {
    String firstnameText = firstname.getText().toString();
    String lastnameText = lastname.getText().toString();
    String phoneText = phone.getText().toString();
    String cityText = city.getText().toString();
    String zipText = zip.getText().toString();
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); //Generate random ID but I 
                                                 think this would generate a 
                                                 new ID each time the data is     
                                                 saved

    if (firstnameText != null)
        PreferenceConnector.writeString(this, PreferenceConnector.FIRSTNAME,
                firstnameText);
    if (lastnameText != null)
        PreferenceConnector.writeString(this, PreferenceConnector.LASTNAME,
                lastnameText);

    if (phoneText != null && !phoneText.equals(""))
        PreferenceConnector.writeLong(this, PreferenceConnector.PHONE,
                Long.parseLong(phoneText));

    if (cityText != null)
        PreferenceConnector.writeString(this, PreferenceConnector.CITY,
                cityText);

    if (zipText != null && !zipText.equals(""))
        PreferenceConnector.writeInteger(this, PreferenceConnector.ZIP,
                Integer.parseInt(zipText));

    if (uuid != null) //what next?

    startActivity(new Intent(PreferencesActivity.this, Main.class));                        
}
```

Comment: That depends on how you've implemented `PreferenceConnector` btw. Oh, and your `if (phoneText != null && !phoneText.equals(""))`-style statements - those should definitely be replaced by a nice and normal `if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneText))`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a Boolean SharedPreference that is initialy set to false and then set to true the foirst time an ID is generated, then you check this boolean before generating and ID and only generate if it is false so basicly

```
//get idHasBeenGenerated from prefs with default false
if(!idHasBeenGenerated)
{
//generate ID
//change value of idHasBeenGenerated to true and save in shared prefs.
}
```

Edit:

```
SharedPreferences prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean idHasBeenGenerated = prefs.getBoolean("idgenerated", false);

if(!idHasBeenGenerated){
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

//do your thing with PreferenceConnector
    Editor editor=prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("idgenerated", true);
    editor.commit();
}else{          
    //Do nothing ID has already been generated
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on this some more? I'm starting to understand but not enough to implement it. Thanks

Comment: Awesome. This makes a lot more sense. Now how do I access the uuid string? It says it's a local variable and I'm unable to use it later in my program.

Comment: Im assuming you are using the PreferenceConnector to somehow save these values? So where I have //do your thing... you would use the PreferenceConnector to save the ID just like you save the other values. Then get it from wherever if is saved when needed.