# Setting a Unique ID at Application Install - Android

Tags: java, android, installation, uuid

I'm trying to implement the code found below so that I can generate a random ID number for the user right when the app is installed. I just have a couple questions.

1. If I create a new file for this (Install.java) how do I access the ID in another class?
2. How do I make sure that this part of the program is executed when the app is first installed? Right now, the program starts on my Main.java class (I'm new to Java). Will it just run when the app is installed?

   ```
   public class Install {

   private static String sID = null;
   private static final String INSTALLATION = "INSTALLATION";

   public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
       if (sID == null) {  
           File installation = new File(context.getFilesDir(), INSTALLATION);
           try {
               if (!installation.exists())
                   writeInstallationFile(installation);
               sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
           }
       }
       return sID;
   }

   private static String readInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
       RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
       byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
       f.readFully(bytes);
       f.close();
       return new String(bytes);
   }

   private static void writeInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
       String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
       out.write(id.getBytes());
       out.close();
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: I urge you not to write to a file (you don't know about what devices are available to all makes and models of phones), but instead use a Preferences or SharedPreferences object. In addition to this, you can leverage off the BackupManager so if the user installs the app on another phone, BackupManager will copy across any stored preferences to the new phone.

Comment: @RichardGreen Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to implement this using  a SharedPreference now, but I'm having a lot of trouble. Could you take a look at my other post and tell me where and I how I would implement it in the code given? Here's a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177092/saving-user-id-in-shared-preferences-android/9177246#9177246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you don't get a way to run any arbitrary code right after installation is complete.

I think the closest you can get is make a check inside your MainActivity onCreate() method that determines whether or not this is the first run (a good way to check this might be to get a reference to your file and call file.exists(), the resulting boolean will tell you whether or not you need to create your UID file.

Comment: So include this in my main activity instead of a separate class?

Comment: or invoke `Install.id` as the first thing in your main activity, if you want to keep this logic in a separate class. (yes, I know this comment is 6 years late)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code I use - feel free to adapt as you will...

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    Log.d(Tag, "Yay onCreate!"); // sorry sometimes I'm a bit verbose with my logs...
    createVerifierStrings();
    .....


 private void createVerifierStrings() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Someprefstringreference", 0);
    String not_set = "NOTSET";
    String android_key;
    android_key = prefs.getString("id", not_set);

    if (android_key.equals(not_set)) {
        Log.d(Tag, "Creating keys for 1st time");
        android_key = generateRandomEnoughStuff();
        prefs.edit().putString("id", android_key).commit();
    }
    ......
```

Comment: Just to add - you can't generate a string upon initialisation - well you can start messing around with services etc etc but you are better off (I think) just doing this the first time the app runs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post from Tim Bray that explains what you actually should be doing..

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html